# Open file in vba Excel environment

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going to use this code to open my file.
But it seems to be the mistake in my last line (myShell.Run "path").

My code:

```
Sub open_path()

Dim path As String

path = ActiveCell.Value

Dim myShell As Object

Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

myShell.Run "path" 'this line is error

End Sub
```

Can I specify an address as a variable ?

Comment: You need to remove the double quotes: _myShell.Run path_ And _path_ should contain a valid file. If this is not the cause of the error you need to describe the error.

Comment: Is it an Excel file you're trying to open?

Comment: I'm trying to open a pdf file.

Comment: What files are valid files?

Comment: Don't use `myShell` at all, instead open it as a hyperlink: `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink path`

Comment: If you do want to use `myShell`, you'd need to provide a path to the prpoer executable for the file type you're trying to open, and then feed it the file path, like so: `myShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"" """ & path & """"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following fix

```
Sub open_path()

    Dim path As String

    path = ActiveCell.Value

    Dim myShell As Object

    Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    myShell.Run Chr(34) & path & Chr(34)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and attention.  
Yes it was right.  
Thankful.